# serial sensor data - eliminate unwanted strings

Tags: python

I am using some python code to sample a sensor connected to the serial port.

Most of the time this works very well. However occasionally the output from the sensor is not correct:

```
['\x80', '19.38', '22.7', '649', 'w\\'] - correct
['\x80', '19.46', '22.7', '648', 'wZ'] - correct
['\x80', '19.49', '22.7', '650', 'w'] - correct
['w', '\x80', '19.45', '22.7', '650'] - error
```

This is causing a lot of problems with my code. I was just wondering if anyone knows how to either start splitting the string with the value after the '\x80' or another way around this?

For Example:

If the string I receive from the sensor is called 'receive' then my code is

```
Var1,Var2,Var3,Var4,Var5 = receive.split()
```

Now I need to convert Var2 to float so I can do some maths on it

```
Var2float = float(Var2)
```

This works most of the time when Var2 is a value like 19.38 until the output of the sensor shifts and Var2 becomes '/x80' which can not be converted to float

Any ideas on how to filter or bypass this sensor output error?

Comment: Like `if Var1 != '\x80': continue`?

Comment: You can put it in a `try except` clause and if `ValueError` exception is raised just give it any value you want.

Comment: You should make sure your low level serial reading routine skips anything at the beginning of the input until it finds '\x80', this way your main routine gets well formed packets. Catching possible ValueError exceptions from the float() conversion would help too.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `try except` clause will solve the issue:

```
my_buffer = ['\x80', '19.38', '22.7', '649', 'w\\']
converted_buffer = []
for v in my_buffer:
    try:
        converted_buffer.append(float(v))
    except ValueError:
        print "{} cannot be converted, skipping to the next".format(v)
print converted_buffer
```

**Output**:

```
� cannot be converted, skipping to the next
w\ cannot be converted, skipping to the next
[19.38, 22.7, 649.0]
```

You can iterate the buffer and when `ValueError` raises just decide what to do with the value, At this case we just print it out, You can log it or do with it what ever you want.

**Note**: I think it's a `sync frame` from the device meaning `\x80` says it's the beginning of the transmission , A lot of sensors has begin and end sync frames.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I can think of is to use a regex to find the end of the `\x80` substring, and split the string starting from there.

Here's an example

```
import re

data = [
    r'\x80 19.38 22.7 649 w\\',
    r'\x80 19.46 22.7 648 wZ',
    r'\x80 19.49 22.7 650 w',
    r'w \x80 19.45 22.7 650',
]

for record in data:
    m = re.search(r' \\x80 \s+ ', record, flags=re.X)
    if m:
        values = record[m.end():].split()
        print(values)
```

**output**

```
['19.38', '22.7', '649', 'w\\\\']
['19.46', '22.7', '648', 'wZ']
['19.49', '22.7', '650', 'w']
['19.45', '22.7', '650']
```

Answer (score 0):

The general concept would first involve buffering the data, second checking if you have a whole sequence, and third extracting the sequence. The class below makes buffering possible and reading and peeking single bytes possible.

```
class MySerialBuffer:
    def __init__(self):
      self.buffer = []
    def peek(self):
      return self.buffer[0]
    def read(self):
      return self.buffer.pop(0)
    def count(self):
      return len(self.buffer)
    def fill(self, new):
      self.buffer = self.buffer + new
    def extract(self):
      while self.count() > 0 and self.peek() != '\x80':
        self.read()
      if self.count() < 4:
        return None
      self.read()
      return (self.read(), self.read(), self.read())
    def __iter__(self):
      while True:
        out = self.extract()
        if out is None:
          return
        yield out

  msb = MySerialBuffer()
  msb.fill(['\x80', '19.38', '22.7', '649'])
  msb.fill(['\x80', '19.38', '22.7', '649'])
  msb.fill(['w', '\x80', '33.4', '19.38', '22.7', '649', 'f', 'w'])
  msb.fill(['\x80', '19.38', '22.7', '649', 'w'])

  for reading in msb:
    print(reading)
```

It *can* be greatly improved performance wise. Also depending on how you read the data it could greatly be simplified and performance increased by handling your data differently, since I wrote the class to work with what you provided in your question. You may be reading actual integer values and you could process them as they are read into the buffer. Also you could use a more efficient system than a `list` if you are processing lots of samples per second to help out. The list is inefficient and appending new items and also the `pop` operation is inefficient. However, there exist other primitive collections that can handle these types of operations more efficiently such as a `Queue`.